# Adding a NuGet package to a project without Visual Studio

Tags: c#, powershell, nuget

I'm trying to automate adding NuGet packages to project on a remote server that doesn't have Visual Studio (nor any build servers) installed. I do know how to use NuGet.exe from my C# code, but this executable only downloads packages and doesn't do any other required work (adding references, executing ps scripts etc). What do I do in order to fully install a package?

Note: I don't need to update a package for my own app, I need to add a package to an arbitrary .csproj file on the server. I'm building a Web-based .Net IDE, and need my users to be able to add packages to their projects.

I see two possibilities: one is using some kind of functionality not present in NuGet.exe, but ratherin some other library (maybe a VS addin), but I don't know where to look for it. The other is to simulate some kind of NuGet Powershell console and send commands to it, but again, I don't know how to do that.

Comment: _need my users to be able to add packages to their projects_, what do you mean by that?

Comment: A user should be able to create a project online and add Nuget packages to it, just like you do in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to consider [SharpDevelop](https://github.com/mrward/SharpDevelop/tree/nuget).

[Installing NuGet Packages outside of Visual Studio](http://community.sharpdevelop.net/blogs/mattward/archive/2011/06/12/InstallingNuGetPackagesOutsideVisualStudio.aspx) an article about the functionality you are trying to achieve (written by Matt Ward, one of the project contributors) says:

> Since NuGet uses PowerShell the simplest approach was to extend the
>   existing PowerShell cmdlets included with SharpDevelop. Now you can
>   write a few lines of PowerShell script to install a NuGet package into
>   a project that has never had a NuGet package before, have the project
>   itself updated and any package PowerShell scripts run. All this from
>   the command line without Visual Studio open.

Comment: I think this deserves the answer btw.

Comment: This must be the one I'm looking for. The only problem is, I can't load the Cmdlets package -- PowerShell keeps throwing FileLoadException. Nevertheless, if only I could make it work calling straight from the .Net code, that would be even better than executing a PS command. So, how do I call it from .Net?

Comment: @ulu - You would have needed to use x86 powershell to call into this module

Answer (score 0):

Just to add an additional answer in-line with Alex's post about SharpDevelop, you have a couple different options.

- Use Nuget.exe ([Related Blog post](http://blog.davidebbo.com/2011/01/installing-nuget-packages-directly-from.html))
- NuGet Addin for MonoDevelop and Xamarin Studio (see [GitHub](https://github.com/mrward/monodevelop-nuget-addin))
- ASP.NET Pages using WebMatrix (see this [video](http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/mvcConf/mvcConf-2-Phil-Haack-The-NuGet-y-Goodness-of-Delivering-Packages))

All of this info is from the [Nuget FAQ](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/start-here/nuget-faq).

Comment: Nuget.exe is what I started with, but it just downloads packages, it doesn't modify project files nor does any other required action. As for various addins, remember I need it for a project hosted on a server that has no IDE installed.

Comment: I did it using NuGet.exe as you suggested, with some additional code, see http://ivonna.biz/blog/2014/9/21/installing-a-nuget-package-programmatically.aspx